# Ruby on Rails - Paperclip and dynamic parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm writing some image upload code for Ruby on Rails with Paperclip, and I've got a working solution but it's very hacky so I'd really appreciate advice on how to better implement it. I have an 'Asset' class containing information about the uploaded images including the Paperclip attachment, and a 'Generator' class that encapsulates sizing information. Each 'Project' has multiple assets and generators; all Assets should be resized according to the sizes specified by each generator; each Project therefore has a certain set of sizes that all of its assets should have.

Generator model:

```
class Generator < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :height, :width

  belongs_to :project

  def sym
    "#{self.width}x#{self.height}".to_sym
  end
end
```

Asset model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :filename,
    :image # etc.
  attr_accessor :generators

  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => lambda { |a| a.instance.styles }

  belongs_to :project

  # this is utterly horrendous
  def styles
    s = {}
    if @generators == nil
      @generators = self.project.generators
    end

    @generators.each do |g|
      s[g.sym] = "#{g.width}x#{g.height}"
    end
    s
  end
end
```

Asset controller create method:

```
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @asset = Asset.new
    @asset.generators = @project.generators
    @asset.update_attributes(params[:asset])
    @asset.project = @project
    @asset.uploaded_by = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @asset.save_(current_user)
        @project.last_asset = @asset
        @project.save

        format.html { redirect_to project_asset_url(@asset.project, @asset), notice: 'Asset was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @asset, status: :created, location: @asset }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @asset.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem I am having is a chicken-egg issue: the newly created Asset doesn't know which generators (size specifications) to use until after it's been instantiated properly. I tried using @project.assets.build, but then the Paperclip code is still executed before the Asset gets its project association set and nils out on me.

The 'if @generators == nil' hack is so the update method will work without further hacking in the controller.

All in all it feels pretty bad. Can anyone suggest how to write this in a more sensible way, or even an approach to take for this kind of thing?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This question and it's answers helped a lot to build same feature in my App. Thanks for everyone! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into the same Paperclip chicken/egg issue on a project trying to use dynamic styles based on the associated model with a polymorphic relationship. I've adapted my solution to your existing code. An explanation follows:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :deferred_image
  attr_writer :deferred_image

  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => lambda { |a| a.instance.styles }

  belongs_to :project

  after_save :assign_deferred_image

  def styles
    project.generators.each_with_object({}) { |g, hsh| hsh[g.sym] = "#{g.width}x#{g.height}" }
  end

  private
  def assign_deferred_image
    if @deferred_image
      self.image = @deferred_image
      @deferred_image = nil
      save!
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, to get around the issue of Paperclip trying to retrieve the dynamic styles before the project relation information has been propagated, you can assign all of the `image` attributes to a non-Paperclip attribute (in this instance, I have name it `deferred_image`). The `after_save` hook assigns the value of `@deferred_image` to `self.image`, which kicks off all the Paperclip jazz.

Your controller becomes:

```
# AssetsController
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @asset = @project.assets.build(params[:asset])
  @asset.uploaded_by = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    # all this is unrelated and can stay the same
  end
end
```

And the view:

```
<%= form_for @asset do |f| %>
  <%# other asset attributes %>
  <%= f.label :deferred_upload %>
  <%= f.file_field :deferred_upload %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This solution also allows using `accepts_nested_attributes` for the `assets` relation in the `Project` model (which is currently how I'm using it - to upload assets as part of creating/editing a Project).

There are some downsides to this approach (ex. validating the Paperclip `image` in relation to the validity of the `Asset` instance gets tricky), but it's the best I could come up with short of monkey patching Paperclip to somehow defer execution of the `style` method until after the association information had been populated.

I'll be keeping an eye on this question to see if anyone has a better solution to this problem!

---

At the very least, if you choose to keep using your same solution, you can make the following stylistic improvement to your `Asset#styles` method:

```
def styles
  (@generators || project.generators).each_with_object({}) { |g, hsh| hsh[g.sym] = "#{g.width}x#{g.height}" }
end
```

Does the exact same thing as your existing method, but more succinctly.

Answer (score 5):

While I really like Cade's solution, just a suggestion. It seems like the 'styles' belong to a project...so why aren't you calculating the generators there?

For example:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :filename,
  :image # etc.
   attr_accessor :generators

   has_attached_file :image,
     :styles => lambda { |a| a.instance.project.styles }
end


 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   ....

   def styles
     @generators ||= self.generators.inject {} do |hash, g|
       hash[g.sym] = "#{g.width}x#{g.height}"
     end
   end
end
```

EDIT: Try changing your controller to (assuming the project has many assets):

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @asset = @project.assets.new
  @asset.generators = @project.generators
  @asset.update_attributes(params[:asset])
  @asset.uploaded_by = current_user
end
```

Comment: While the question where to locate the actual styles method is an interesting one, this won't work with a new record. In the styles lambda, `a.instance.project` will be `nil` until the record has been saved, so you'll get a `NoMethodError` on `nil`.

Comment: I edited my solution...I'm sure that instance must be pointing to the @asset variable? If you alter the controller as I did, then it should already have the project inside a hidden instance variable for paperclip to use...

Comment: Rails shots an error on a Project model, styles action. Says: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end`

Answer (score 3):

I've just solved a similar problem that I had.
In my "styles" lambda I am returning a different style depending on the value of a "category" attribute. The problem though is that Image.new(attrs), and image.update_attributes(attrs) doesn't set the attributes in a predictable order, and thus I can't be guaranteed that image.category will have a value before my styles lambda is called. My solution was to override attributes=() in my Image model as follows:

```
class Image
  ...
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => my_lambda, ...
  ...
  def attributes=(new_attributes, guard_protected_attributes = true)
    return unless new_attributes.is_a?(Hash)
    if new_attributes.key?("image")
      only_attached_file    = {
        "image" => new_attributes["image"]
      }
      without_attached_file = new_attributes
      without_attached_file.delete("image") 
      # set the non-paperclip attributes first
      super(without_attached_file, guard_protected_attributes)
      # set the paperclip attribute(s) after
      super(only_attached_file, guard_protected_attributes)
    else
      super(new_attributes, guard_protected_attributes)
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

This ensures that the paperclip attribute is set after the other attributes and can thus use them in a :style lambda.

It clearly won't help in situations where the paperclip attribute is "manually" set. However in those circumstances you can help yourself by specifying a sensible order. In my case I could write:

```
image = Image.new
image.category = "some category"
image.image = File.open("/somefile") # styles lambda can use the "category" attribute
image.save!
```

(Paperclip 2.7.4, rails 3, ruby 1.8.7)